# Enumerate registered URL Schemes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is it possible to enumerate all [URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference.pdf) registered on an iOS device at run-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no facility to do this.